# Why can't this find the namespace I'm referencing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

When I run my application it's throwing an error and highlighting this line in the web.config:

```
<add namespace="Telerik.Reporting" />
```

When I look at the references for my project, I can see that it's there and it's path is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Reporting Q3 2014\Bin\Telerik.Reporting.dll
```

In my controller, I can put `using Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc;` and there's no problem. But when I try to reference it from my razor view it can't find it, and as mentioned above if I try to add the namespace from the web.config I get an error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to add this name space under Views/web.config

Comment: I tried that too. Turned out I had to set copy local to true for the references in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set copy local to true for the references I had this issue with. I'm not sure if that's normal or if it's something special to do with the telerik assemblies though.